# R Ctree how to get the "n" in a terminal node

Tags: r

```
library("caret")
library("randomForest")
library("party")
library("tree")
library("rpart")
library("rpart.plot")
library("survAUC")
library("survival")
options(digits=4)    
survivalTree<-ctree(Surv(survData$user_age,survData$is_user_active)~.,data=survData)
plot(survivalTree)
```

in the following code i've created this Ctree

example of the data set

[image]

Tree looks like this:

[image]

My question is how do I get the 'n' variable in the terminal nodes..

lets say in node 4 which is terminal, n = 17. How do i get this value of "17"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where`-function extracts the `where` slot in a BinaryTree object, and you can tabulate it. I don't have your data, but with a similar set of commands is used the ovarian data set in pkg:survival and get:

```
 > where(survivalTree)
[1] 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2
```

So to see how many cases were in node-3, it would be:

```
 stbl<- table( where(survivalTree) 
stbl[names(stbl)==3]
3 
8
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You're a god! ;>